# How do I write a String flattener?

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to write a string flattener in Java, that converts the following pattern to the specified form.

```
{ x:1, y:1, z:{ a:1, b:2 } }
```

flattens to

```
{ x:1, y:1, z.a:1, z.b:2 }
```

I plan to use a stack to add the contents between `{` and `}` and pop the contents back after parsing `}`, although, this gets complicated. Is there any other simpler way of doing this in Java?

Comment: What if the input is `{x:1, y:1, z:{a:1,b:{c:2}}}`

Comment: The stack solution sounds good to me.  Any reason why you don't want to use this?

Comment: From a computer science standpoint, you will definitely need some kind of (unbounded) memory to keep track of which labels you are currently nested in. A stack is the most appropriate structure for this problem.

Comment: You may use a parser generated from a grammar (by a parser generator). Almost all generated parsers use a stack for this problem, so there is no difference in the approach. If the syntax is as simple as you mentioned (only numbers and ASCII-chars), then a handcoded parser will be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Using a stack isn't complicated at all. Pseudocode:

```
read beginObject;
while(peekAtNext != endObject && !stack.isEmpty) {
  read name;
  read value;
  if(value == beginObject) {
    push name;
  } else if (value == endObject) {
    pop name;
  } else {
    write(fullStack + "." + name);
    write(".");
    write(value);
  }
}
read endAbject;
```

There's isn't any way to do this that is significantly simpler than that.